# MySQL Don't INSERT If NULL Fields

Tags: mysql

How would I NOT do any INSERTs for the following statement if `inventory.nick` was `NULL?` Thank you in advance!

```
INSERT INTO gold_log (nick, amount, stream_online, modification_type, dt) 
    SELECT inventory.nick, SUM(inventory.stat_2*.01), False, 12, NOW()
    FROM inventory
        INNER JOIN equipment_shoes ON
        inventory.id=equipment_shoes.id
        AND inventory.item=8
        INNER JOIN gold_log ON 
        inventory.nick=gold_log.nick
        AND gold_log.dt > FROM_UNIXTIME(1423421534.32);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add that condition in the where clause?

```
INSERT INTO gold_log (nick, amount, stream_online, modification_type, dt) 
    SELECT inventory.nick, SUM(inventory.stat_2*.01), False, 12, NOW()
    FROM inventory
        INNER JOIN equipment_shoes ON
        inventory.id=equipment_shoes.id
        AND inventory.item=8
        INNER JOIN gold_log ON 
        inventory.nick=gold_log.nick
        AND gold_log.dt > FROM_UNIXTIME(1423421534.32);
    HAVING
        inventory.nick IS NOT NULL
```

*(Changed `WHERE` to `HAVING` because of implicit grouping caused by the `SUM`)*

Additionally, you can make the column itself not nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE inventory MODIFY COLUMN nick VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL;
```

But that alone won't solve the issue. If the column is not nullable, and the column has a default value, all new rows get this default value if `nick` was empty in the query. If it doesn't have a default value, then the insert will fail completely, including those rows that do have a `nick` filled in. So the change to the insert statement itself is the most important: it will just skip those rows that don't have a `nick`.

Comment: I had to use `HAVING inventory.nick IS NOT NULL` instead of `WHERE inventory.nick IS NOT NULL`. Using `WHERE` still yielded NULL results for some reason.

Comment: Ah, I actually didn't notice the aggregation (`SUM`) in the query. Normally you would need a `GROUP BY` clause as well, but MySQL allows you to do it without. Anyway, even with an implicit group by, you might need to use `HAVING`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `IS NOT NULL` criteria:

```
INSERT INTO gold_log (nick, amount, stream_online, modification_type, dt) 
    SELECT inventory.nick, SUM(inventory.stat_2*.01), False, 12, NOW()
    FROM inventory
        INNER JOIN equipment_shoes ON
        inventory.id=equipment_shoes.id
        AND inventory.item=8
        INNER JOIN gold_log ON 
        inventory.nick=gold_log.nick
        AND gold_log.dt > FROM_UNIXTIME(1423421534.32)
        WHERE inventory.nick IS NOT NULL;
```